# Embed OSM idEditor into another website

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm in the process of making a website that enables users to add street names to an OSM map.

The website will have only one functionality, which is adding street names for unnamed streets.

I want to create this website for my hometown, because streets in my hometown are not named. So, I want to provide an easy way for the locals in my community to suggest and add street names for unnamed streets.

I've used idEditor and I like the feature where I can click on a street and it will give me the option of changing a street name, or add one if none already exists.

I want to use this UI in my future website, so that the website basically has a map, the user comes and chooses a street (like in idEditor) and the user will be prompted to enter a street name.

Pretty simple I guess, but my experience in web development is pretty minimal and I don't really know where to start from.

I would appreciate any guidance or help.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just forward the users to the OSM website with the region of your city? This will cost you almost zero time for maintenance compared to running and regularly updating your own iD instance. Apart from that, just read the [iD Installation](https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD#installation) guide at GitHub.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/62486/embed-ideditor-into-another-website